# Setting the collection view width according to the label width

Tags: swift, uikit, width, cell, collectionview

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
    
    func textSize(text: String) -> CGSize {
        let attributes = [NSAttributedString.Key.font: UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 17)]
        return text.size(withAttributes: attributes)
    }
    
    let locationText = locationLabel.text ?? "" 
    let padding: CGFloat = 16
    
    let textSize = textSize(text: locationText)
    let cellWidth = textSize.width + padding
    
    return CGSize(width: cellWidth, height: collectionView.frame.height / 2.1)
}
```

**This is the code I use.**

[image]
**Collection view cells look like this. What is the problem ?**

Comment: Can you please clarify what part of the picture your question is about? Is it all of the overlayed text near the top or it about the row containing a picture, two labels, and an icon? If the latter, what are you expecting to be different? Regarding the code, what is `locationLabel`? Do you actually intend every cell to be the same size? That code makes no attempt to give a value specific to the given indexPath.

Comment: I think the problem is pretty clear in the picture. In the upper part, the cells are intertwined. There is no error in my code but it is not working properly. LocationLabel is irrelevant now. Give width based on label inside any cell.